# Concat in eloquent update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How I can update multiple objects with `CONCAT` in a single query?

The following code works, but it is not safe:

```
Table::whereIn('id', $idArray)->where('user_id', $this->userId)
            ->update([
                'title' => DB::raw('CONCAT(title,'.$form->newPart.')')
            ]);
```

Another method that I have tried is the following, however it does not work:

```
Table::whereIn('id', $idArray)->where('user_id', $this->userId)
            ->update([
                'title' => DB::raw('CONCAT(title,?)', [$form->newPart])
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will just have to call the `setBindings` method.

```
    Table::whereIn('id', $idArray)->where('user_id', $this->userId)
        ->update([
            'title' => DB::raw('CONCAT(title, ?)')
        ])
        ->setBindings([$form->newPart]);
```

Comment: Not working - "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"

Comment: This will not work, It will throw an Fatal error,
Call to a member function setBindings() on integer

Answer (score 1):

I came here from a search due to a similar problem. Your question helped me find a solution here it is:

```
Table::whereIn('id', $idArray)->where('user_id', $userId)
                ->update([
                    'title' => DB::raw("CONCAT(title,'$title')")
                ],$title);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To help ensure your response is helpful to others with similar issues, could you add a little more description about how your solution works?

Comment: If $title goes anywhere near user input then you just created the conditions for a potential injection attack

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
$word_to_concat = "xxx";

    DB::table('food')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update([      'name_of_column' => DB::raw("CONCAT(name_of_column, '".$word_to_concat."')")  ,'state' => 'off'    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = 'two ';
$ids = implode(',',[1,2]);
DB::statement("update table set column = 
case when column is null or column ='' then 'one ' 
else concat(column,'$title') end where id in($ids)");
```